# MySql table lock in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, pdo, locking

I am making a webservice in PHP which does a series of calculations based on a select from a table and then updates the table afterwards with the new results.

However i want to prevent the case where another person is making a call to the same webservice while another person's session is still doing an update.

Is it the right thing here to lock that entire table and then unlock it again? If so, how do i lock and unlock a mysql table using PHP pdo?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I don't think this is any problem. The calculations and fetching data from the database is done within a few milliseconds. The chances or two people interacting at the same time is soooo small that most people don't bother making a lock like this.

Comment: I do realise that. However i am not willing to take risks as data corruption could have big consequences for my application.

Comment: You want to use [database transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html), to ensure atomicity of operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a comment:

> Not a direct answer, but I don't think this is any problem. The
>   calculations and fetching data from the database is done within a few
>   milliseconds. The chances or two people interacting at the same time
>   is soooo small that most people don't bother making a lock like this.

But if these calculations are critical you could prevent this problem by adding a new field and simply call it `occupied`, `busy` or something like that.

When you run your script, check if this field is set to for example 1, if it is, make the script sleep for 1-2-3 seconds and then retry. If this field is set to 0, update it to 1, do the calculations and set it back to 0 again.

This would prevent two people from accessing the same values at the same time.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if both clients read the value of the check field before either has updated it, they will both think that they can proceed.  One needs the CPU to perform operations *atomically* in order to ensure safety in concurrent applications: operating systems provide an API for this, and the RDBMS calls that API in implementing its locking mechanisms.  **Don't try to build this yourself** as it's doomed to fail.  Instead, use the atomicity provided by database transactions: it's what they're there for.

Comment: This seems like the safest to implement solution i'm willing to go this route. Would there be any possible solution to prevent the case eggyal mentioned?

Comment: @eggyal: Read the other answer posted here. It is not possible that two people access this at the exact same time. It is done too fast for that to happen.

Comment: The other answer is correct in that it relies on the RDBMS to perform locking.  Your answer is incorrect in that it relies on a read/write happening "too fast" for a race hazard to arise, which will not always be the case.

Comment: I went for the approach with the boolean in the database. I simple did an update  statement on the "occupied" boolean that put it on true and then checked how many rows i affected with this statement. If i affect one row then i know i can do my calculations. If i don't affect a row then i know another session is busy doing the calculations. Preventing faulty/corrupt data. 

this might not be the most efficient solution but it's what worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

Database Management Systems like MySQL are smart enough to prevent concurrency violations like these.

Look for database isolation levels (read uncommitted, read commited, repeatable read, serializable) and the possible problems (dirty read, non repeatable read ...) -> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29).

Personally, I would not recommend a table lock in your case. You better **wrap your calculations and database operations in a transaction** and rely on the DBMS to manage your stuff.

Comment: However i am doing it like this at the moment:
1)Do a select on my table
2)Do my calculations in PHP based on that select
3)Update that table based on the PHP calculations.

Is that possible in transaction? I am relatively new to databases.

Comment: @user1574041: You can use a [locking read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) such as `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.  However, you may also find that you can transfer your calculation logic out of PHP and into SQL, such that it is performed in a single `UPDATE` statement e.g. `UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = (1+myColumn)*2 WHERE ...`.

Comment: Thanks @eggyal, would be my recommendation too. If you decide that you have to do the calculations in php and don't want to lock the whole table, you might want to look at a filebase locking mechanism like `flock`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: @DavidMüller: `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` only locks the selected records, not the whole table.

Comment: Is this possible with MyISAM? As far as I know, MyISAM only supports locking on table level.

Comment: I have to do my calculations in PHP since i do not have access to stored procedures. In that case the only solution is a lock or?

Comment: @DavidMüller: No, it's not possible with MyISAM.  But your entire answer is not possible with MyISAM, which doesn't support transactions.

Comment: @user1574041: One doesn't necessarily need stored procedures in order to move calculation logic into SQL, as my example above shows.